# How to find the relationship, or ratio, between these hex colors?

Tags: python, rgb

I'm looking to implement something similar to http://colorschemedesigner.com/ in my program I'm writing, and so I've taken 3 sample colors, and all the colors that the tool found that fits within the scheme, and I would like to reverse-engineer the pattern here, to try and figure out how to create my own tool, since he doesn't provide an API, as far as I can tell.

I've pulled the 3 colors here, one degree of hue apart from each other, the colors are as follows, with the master color being the color I entered into the tool.

```
     color      RBG        HLS
mstr hex: FF0000 255 0 0 (0.0, 0.5, 1.0)
frst hex: BF3030 191 48 48 (0.0, 0.46862745098039216, 0.5983263598326359)
scnd hex: A60000 166 0 0 (0.0, 0.3254901960784314, 1.0)
thrd hex: FF4040 255 64 64 (0.0, 0.6254901960784314, 1.0)
frth hex: FF7373 255 115 115 (0.0, 0.7254901960784313, 1.0)
     color      RBG        HLS
hex: FF0700 255 7 0 (0.004575163398692812, 0.5, 1.0)
hex: BF3330 191 51 48 (0.003496503496503489, 0.46862745098039216, 0.5983263598326359)
hex: A60400 166 4 0 (0.004016064257028125, 0.3254901960784314, 1.0)
hex: FF4540 255 69 64 (0.004363001745200675, 0.6254901960784314, 1.0)
hex: FF7673 255 118 115 (0.0035714285714285956, 0.7254901960784313, 1.0)
     color      RBG        HLS
hex: FF0D00 255 13 0 (0.008496732026143797, 0.5, 1.0)
hex: BF3730 191 55 48 (0.00815850815850816, 0.46862745098039216, 0.5983263598326359)
hex: A60800 166 8 0 (0.008032128514056233, 0.3254901960784314, 1.0)
hex: FF4940 255 73 64 (0.007853403141361256, 0.6254901960784314, 1.0)
hex: FF7A73 255 122 115 (0.008333333333333378, 0.7254901960784313, 1.0)
```

Added 180 degrees of hue: `#00CC00`

```
    color      RBG        HLS
hex: 00CC00 0 204 0 (0.3333333333333333, 0.4, 1.0)
hex: 269926 38 153 38 (0.3333333333333333, 0.37450980392156863, 0.6020942408376962)
hex: 008500 0 133 0 (0.3333333333333333, 0.2607843137254902, 1.0)
hex: 39E639 57 230 57 (0.3333333333333333, 0.5627450980392157, 0.7757847533632286)
hex: 67E667 103 230 103 (0.3333333333333333, 0.6529411764705882, 0.7175141242937852)
```

I've done a few basic substractions to see if I could find the relationship by hand, for example, the master and the 2nd color are 65% different, then roughly 59% different, then 0% different, just based of the second colors R, G, or B's value divided by the master's same value.

**My question is: Is there some Python package that could help me out with this? Failing that is there some ratio that I am missing?**

edit: I got curious and started looking through his js source code to try and figure out how he does it, but I'm not anywhere near close to understanding it. I've uploaded here: http://tankorsmash.com/transfers/csd3.js since it's over the pastebin limit.

Comment: I've approached the author of CSD3 and he mentioned he's 'about to start' the API, so that's good news.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the HSL and HSV color models: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

There is library support in [PIL](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-hsl.htm)

Comment: I converted some of the colors to HLS, and will update the question accordingly, but I still am unable to see a pattern